# jquery check if nothing selected in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I want to check if a selectbox has selected an item or is empty. If option is selected no problem, I can use

`$('main_user_selector_selectbox').find('option:selected').val()` to get the value or `$('main_user_selector_selectbox')find.('option:selected').text()` to get the text.

Issue is, when nothing is selected I always receive the information of first option.

```
<select class="main_user_selector_selectbox" name="main_user_select_box">
    <option value="US20160622053653am"> Beckenbauer, Franz </option>
    <option value="US20160618044520am"> Engel, Laura </option>
    <option value="US20160618094232am"> Gonzaga, Bengie </option>
    <option value="US20160623055042am"> Neureuter, Walter </option>
    <option value="US20160618050746am"> Rosenberger, Trude </option>
    <option value="US20160622102555am"> Schuhmacher, Michael </option>
    <option value="US20160618063016am"> Tinay, Decebil </option>
    <option value="US20160615115928am"> Weiss3, Katrin </option>
</select>
```

I tried this script with datatables to receive some information to allow or disallow selection of rows in datatable.

```
var table = $('#rights_grid').DataTable();
table.on( 'select' , function () {
    var user_id = $(".main_user_selector_selectbox").find('option:selected').val();
    alert(user_id);
}
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty value as the first item in your select box

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Now you can simply check for the value of the select box. It will return nothing if none is selected.

```
$('.main_user_selector_selectbox').val()
```

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy